# Spring Boot Problem because of LSP (failed to refresh live data from process ...)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, liskov-substitution-principle

I just began to use spring boot. My new created project doesn´t work succesfully. 
I want to run the spring boot app with "run as Spring Boot App" but I´ve got the same error as @Vinay Vaishnav. I´ve tried everything covered in the replies.

My first error was: Failed to refresh live data from process ...

[LSP ERROR Before Changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFc3j.png)

After that I included following dependency to the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Because of the added dependency the error is gone but then i´ve got 404

[WhiteLabel Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1GbR.png)

I also added the livereload devtools in the applicationProperties. It doesn´t matter if this line is added or not.

That´s  my code for now:

AppConfiguration.java:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

public class AppConfiguration {

    @RequestMapping("/hello") 
    public String hello() {
        return  "Hello World";
    }
}
```

applicationProperties:

```
spring.devtools.livereload.enabled=true
server.port=8081
```

HelloWorldApplication.java:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class HelloWorldApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloWorldApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My versions:

- Apache Maven 3.6.3
- Spring Boot 2.2.6
- JDK 13.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing how to write down your classes.

First, `@RestController` must be in a class that is going to control the requests. (In your case it should go in AppConfiguration)

With this change it should work.

And you should change the name of your class to AppController. (Just to be more consistent with what the class does)

Comment: Thx very much. Now my HelloWorld text is visible on the browser but the problem with "the Failed to refresh live data from process ..." is still there... Any suggestions?

Comment: Live data is collected with the help of Spring Actuator.

You need to include the following dependency in your pom.xml

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
See https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/wiki/Live-Application-Information#application-requirements-for-spring-boot-projects for reference.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to disable the process tracking in STS preferences, instead of adding the dependency, if the project not actually uses it.

[image]